# Fileset with contains selector for some files but not all

Tags: java, jar, ant, build, fileset

I'm trying to discard `@WebService` annotated classes in my Ant build using `not` and `contains` keywords. However, it isn't working and still includes classes annotated with `@WebService`. Here is the task used to copy sources to the working build directory:

```
<copy todir="${compile.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="**/*" />
        <exclude name="**/*.class" />
        <exclude name="log4j.properties" />
        <exclude name="log4j.properties.*" />
        <exclude name="log4j.xml" />
        <exclude name="log4j.xml.*" />
        <exclude name="*.jocl" />
        <not>
            <contains text="@WebService(" casesensitive="true" />
        </not>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

However, it seems like the `not` section is ignored, and those classes are still copied. Why isn't this working? Is the syntax wrong? Also, how do I add a condition, so that the restriction concerns only `.java` files?

I'm using `Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on July 8 2015`.

Comment: Is `${compile.dir}` empty before each run?  `<copy>` will only take action for any files it sees as needing copy, it won't remove a file it it was copied in a previous run.

Comment: It wasn't. Stupid me counting on implicit clean

Answer (score 1):

*(Perhaps this will guide you, it works for me, but I'm not quite sure I've fully understood your requirement.)*

Try this fileset:

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
  <exclude name="**/*.class" />
  <exclude name="log4j.properties" />
  <exclude name="log4j.properties.*" />
  <exclude name="log4j.xml" />
  <exclude name="log4j.xml.*" />
  <exclude name="*.jocl" />
  <or>
    <filename name="**/*.java" negate="yes" />
    <not>
      <contains text="@WebService(" casesensitive="true" />
    </not>
  </or>
</fileset>
```

A few explanatory comments:

There's no need to specify `<include name="**/*" />` this is implicit in a fileset.

When you include a nested [selector](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) inside a fileset (like `<not>...<contains>...</not>`) this is implicitly ANDed with the patternsets (which are implicitly ORed with each other).  See [`<fileset>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) docs:

> Selectors are available as nested elements within the FileSet. If any
>   of the selectors within the FileSet do not select the file, the file
>   is not considered part of the FileSet. This makes a FileSet equivalent
>   to an `<and>` selector container.

The upshot of this is that you need to use an `<or>` selector container with two negative selectors.  In other words, *"select the file if it's **not** a java file OR it **doesn't** match the text string"*.

The selector container could equivalently be written this way if you prefer:

```
<or>
  <not>
    <filename name="**/*.java" />
  </not>
  <not>
    <contains text="@WebService(" casesensitive="true" />
  </not>
</or>
```